# Не выходит настроить гравитацию для custon_spinner_item

Tags: android, android-layout

Я пытаюсь расположить текст по середине пункта с размером 45dp.

При использовании `android:width="match_parent" выходит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при использовании `android:width="45dp" выходит нужный мне размер, но текст сверху. Вот фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код самого `custom_spinner_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Пробовал выставлять `layout_gravity` на `center_vertical`, но ничего не менялось. Как мне расположить текст по середине, но с высотой пункта 45dp?

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть `TextView` в `FrameLayout` и ему указать `layout_gravity` = `center_vertical`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, тогда программа вылетает. Зная что Вы скажете, вот ошибка - `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView` :В

Comment: Ну так по ошибке же понятно, что вы пытаетесь скастовать ваш новый элемент списка к TextView тогда как он теперь уже FrameLayout. Это дословный перевод ошибки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я знаю! Вы же написали сделать так, вот я и сделал! :) Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Ну так исправьте логику ту, где вы теперь получаете Frame вместо TExtView

Comment: У вас что типа должно быть: TExtView spinerItem=(TExtView ) findViewById(R.id.textView);

Comment: Помимо сообщения об ошибке надо приводить код на строчке на которой ошибка появляется.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, эм... А где прописывать это нахождение `TextView`? Этим занимается адаптер, а у меня его нет (если бы был, там бы и прописал гравитацию).

Comment: Да, ещё можно попробовать без оборачивания в фреймЛэйаут поставить gravity вместо layoutGravity

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, с `android:gravity` прокатило. Добавьте в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать вместо `layout_gravity`, коий указывает расположение элемента в родителе, атрибут `gravity`, коий указывает как располагаться содержимому элемента.

Т.е. надо так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```